# Why doesn't the compiler use directly LSR

Tags: arduino, avr-gcc

Hi I've been working on a project using an Arduino Uno (so ATmega328p) where timing is quite important and so I wanted to see into which instructions the compiler was converting my code. And in there I have a `uint8_t` which I shift one bit to the right on each iteration using `data >>= 1` and it seems the compiler translated this into 5 instructions (`data` is in `r24`):

```
mov     r18, r24
ldi     r19, 0x00
asr     r19
ror     r18
mov     r24, r18
```

But if I look into the instruction set documentation I see an instruction which does exactly this: [`lsr r24`](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_LSR.html)

Do I overlook something or why isn't the compiler using this as well? The registers `r18` and `r19` are not used anywhere else.

I'm using an Ardunio but if I'm correct it does just use the normal `avr-gcc` compiler. This is the code (trimmed) which generates the sequence:

```
ISR(PCINT0_vect) {
    uint8_t data = 0;
    for (uint8_t i = 8; i > 0; --i) {
//        asm volatile ("lsr %0": "+w" (data));
        data >>= 1;
        if (PINB & (1 << PB0))
            data |= 0x80;
    }
    host_data = data;
}
```

As far as I can see the Ardunino IDE is using the AVR gcc compiler provided by the system which is version 6.2.0-1.fc24. Both are installed via the package manger so should be up to date.

Comment: The assembly doesn't seem to correspond to the C code.

Comment: Well I compiled it using the Ardunio IDE and then used `avr-objdump` on the elf file… What is it that doesn't seem to correspond?

Comment: @Eugene Sh.: It **does** correspond to the C code. It corresponds just to the line`data >>= 1;`

Comment: This is one of the cases where "use shifts instead of division" is the wrong advice. If you do /= 2 instead the compiler will generate lsr r24; (tip: try the gcc explorer to play around with asm code generation)

Comment: *What* compiler? What processor? It really should be obvious this is necessary information for the question to make sense.

Comment: Tried to answer both questions.

Comment: The AVR GCC backend has some unfortunate gaps. I remember one time it compiled an ISR consisting of `bytevar--` into something like 8 instructions.

Comment: Voting to close because the issue cannot be reproduced. `avr-gcc` version 6.2.0 mentioned in the question hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Not sure where you got your information but there is the `avr-gcc` package  version 6.2.0 for Fedora 24. https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/avr-gcc

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to C language specification any value whose size is less than the size of `int` (depends on the particular compiler; in your case `int` is 16-bits wide) involved in any operation (in your case `>>`) is upcast to an `int` before the operation.
This behaviour of the compiler is called [*integer promotion*](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules).

And that's exactly what the compiler did:

- r19=0 is the MSByte of the integer promoted value of `data`.
- (r19, r18) represents the total integer promoted value of `data` that is then shifted right by one bit by `asr r19` and `ror 18`.
- The result is then implicitely cast back to your `uint8_t` variable `data`:
  `mov r24, r18`, i.e. the MSByte in r19 is thrown away.

Edit:
Of course the complier *could* optimize the code.
Trying to reproduce the problem I found that at least with 
avr-gcc version 4.9.2 the problem doesn't occur.
It creates very efficient code, i.e. C-line 
 `data >>= 1;` gets compiled to just one single `lsr r24` instruction.
So maybe you are using a very old compiler version.

Comment: Okay but this seems a waste of resources (time and space).

Comment: That's the reason why I still code in assembler on such tiny machines. For interrupt functions, it still seems to be a wise choice.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you can get the compiler to optimize the code by setting the optimization switch (-O...).

Comment: It is already using `-Os` which is (according to the documentation) almost as good as `-O2`. Some are disabled but none of them seem to be related. And previously `-O3` was producing enormous programs.

Comment: It's not a total waste because sometimes you need the unoptimized code for debugging on assembler level. Then you are very glad if you have unoptimized code.

Comment: If I recall correctly -mint8 is the flag to make integers 8-bit. However this has a lot of unwanted side effects. Sorry, can't quite remember what they were now, but I never used the flag because of them. I spent a lot of time comparing avr-gcc with a commercial compiler many years ago.

Comment: Oh that's right, the C standard requires integers to be at least 16-bit, so using -mint8 breaks all the libraries.

Comment: Nigel Jones said in "Efficient C Code for 8-bit Microcontrollers" something like: "...The integer promotion rules of C are probably the most heinous crime committed against those of us who labor in the 8-bit world"...

Comment: So is there any workaround? Like disabling *only* the promotion rules, without breaking ``int`` by making it 8 bit? Because this in fact looks devastating for AVR code.

Comment: @Jonas Wielicki: the best solution for the problem is to use a better compiler. E.g. with avr-gcc version 4.9.2 I cannot reproduce the problem: For C code line `d >>= 1;` I get just one single `lsr r24` instruction. Maybe xZise is using a very old compiler version.

Comment: Well I'm using the packages provided for Fedora 24 (arduino and avr gcc). If I'm reading this correctly arduino is using the installed avr-gcc package which is 6.2.0 for me.

Comment: @DirceuRodriguesJr: A decent compiler for an 8-bit platform should have no problem recognizing cases where the upper word of a 16-bit value isn't used.  A bigger problem is the lack of explicitly-non-promoting types which behave as a particular bit size independent of `int` length.  Some compilers will behave "creatively" if the product of two uint16_t exceeds 2147483647 even if the result is masked with 65535.